# Laravel pagination links problem with the design

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I was using a specific template with assets and plugins in my laravel project. Now I removed the template and deleted the plugins and assets I was using. Now in the data table I have created pagination links appear really weird and it seems nothing can fix them. What can be done in this case.

```
 {{$employees->links()}}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @kris7i. Although showing your end result helps with understanding the problem, to be able to reproduce the problem it is better to share the code that is relevant in creating this end result.

Comment: The same happens to me in Laravel 8. It looks like there is a bug in this links() function.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64013227/4730831
It solves the problem.

Comment: This should fix the issue: `{{$employees->links('pagination::bootstrap-5')}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to paginate manually, so you can add your own styling to it.

```
<!-- a Tag for previous page -->
<a href="{{$employees->previousPageUrl()}}">
    <!-- You can insert logo or text here -->
</a>
@for($i=0;$i<=$employees->lastPage();$i++)
    <!-- a Tag for another page -->
    <a href="{{$employees->url($i)}}">{{$i}}</a>
@endfor
<!-- a Tag for next page -->
<a href="{{$employees->nextPageUrl()}}">
    <!-- You can insert logo or text here -->
</a>
```

You can add your own styling by doing this manually, because when you used `$employees->links()` it will be automatically use bootstrap class name.
Here is the description from laravel docs

> The links method will render the links to the rest of the pages in the result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper page query string variable. Remember, the HTML generated by the links method is compatible with the Bootstrap CSS framework.

Good luck.

Comment: This is crazy when you have a lot of data